# Oracle SQL multiple PL-SQL

Tags: oracle18c

I am new to oracle sql and learning how to use PL-SQL.
Right now, I am trying to run two procedures to insert values into the table.
Each procedures run perfectly fine, inserting the value.
However, error occurs when I am running those two procedure at once.
It returns error of "ORA-06550" I am looking for the solution, yet have not found any

```
Declare
    type array_p is varray(4) of varchar(30);
    pArray array_p := array_p('pink', 'blue', 'midnight', 'starlight');
    
begin
    for i in 1..pArray.count loop
        
        insert into specifications
        values(spec_seq.NextVal, 1, 'A15 Bionic', '128', '6.1', '5G', 173, pArray(i), 180, 10);
        
    end loop;
end;

Declare
    type array_p is varray(4) of varchar(30);
    pArray array_p := array_p('pink', 'blue', 'midnight', 'starlight');
    
begin
    for i in 1..pArray.count loop
        
        insert into specifications
        values(spec_seq.NextVal, 1, 'A15 Bionic', '256', '6.1', '5G', 173, pArray(i), 190, 10);
        
    end loop;
end;
```

Is it bad to make multiple procedures and use it at once? I though procedures are like method in java.

Comment: solved adding '/' at the end;

Comment: Note that neither of these are procedures.  They are anonymous blocks.  Procedures are objects that exist in the database permanently and can be called with different parameter values like a Java method.  I'd expect that you'd want a single procedure that you pass different arguments to here rather than two anonymous blocks.